# Multiple props inside click event

Tags: reactjs

I know I can put multiple functions inside an event handler like this:

```
  onClick={() => {function1(); function2()}}
```

If I need two props inside an event handler, can it be done the same way?

```
  onClick={() => {this.props.prop1(); this.props.prop2()}}
```

Or should they be combined into a single prop prior?

Comment: is `prop1` a function? Do you mean to do `this.props.prop1()`?

Comment: yes. changed it.

Comment: This is fine. There's no sensible way to combine them (other than merging them into a single prop in parent component).

Comment: Thanks. Merging them into a single prop in parent was my thought.

Comment: @MatthewMoon You don't really need to combine them into a single prop. You can put them together into another function as Gautam points out before the render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging them will increase readability

```
combinedFunction(){ 
     this.props.prop1(); 
     this.props.prop2()
    }
```

---

```
onClick={this.combinedFunction}
```